# DOMException occurred in Vue: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vue-component, v-for

Here is my vue project and the bug occurred like this:

1. git clone https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP_online 【I have pushed my branch to the public github】
2. cd JioNLP_online && npm run serve
3. now we have started a local frontend server with an ip and port
4. open the brower and paste `http://ip:port/lecture/lecture_home_page`,and you could see the below webpage, the left navigation part is empty.

[image]

besides, the error printed in the console is like this:

[image]

and the wrong element is like this:

[image]

5，reopen an empty tab page and open `http://ip:port/jionlp_online`, and then jump from this link to the 【NLP教程】navigation bar. now we can see the correct rendering of the navigation part like below:

[image]

and the element is now correct like below:

[image]

**The key problem is open the link `http://ip:port/lecture/lecture_home_page` directly could cause the failed navigation rendering error.**

the corresponing vue components code is in [**LectureNavigation.vue**](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP_online/blob/main/src/views/lecture/LectureNavigation.vue):

[image]

the corresponding navigation content is requested in the `mounted` method from my public backend server.

this bug has already confused me for about one month.

Does anybody could help me check it? Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stemmed from package incompatibilities.

You were using `vue@3` + `@vue/composition-api@1`. Apart from those, you had quite a few linting and typescript errors and some missing dependencies.

To save time, I created a new Vue3 project (with typescript, vuex & router) and copy/pasted your components & folders into it. I added the missing dependencies and fixed a bunch of linting and ts errors.

When serving, I always get the sidebar when navigating to `/lecture/lecture_home_page`:

[image]

[PR-ed here](https://github.com/dongrixinyu/JioNLP_online/pull/1). Read the notes.

---

Take some time to read (and fix) all the Vue warnings in console. Some of them are important.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to JS and Vue. When I debug, build or serve the project on the NodeJS, I always felt frustrated because the eslint is really nasty to use. I'll try to follow your advice to solve it.

Comment: I have reviewed your commit. And I am still worried that if changing the `webpack.config.js` and `vue-config.js` file would have an effect on `npm run build` of the project? Such as the built package is larger or sth else?

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue with Nuxt 3. And I've fixed it by removing all page transitions.